# Can I ask a question to which I already know the answer?

Tags: discussion

This is sort of an etiquette quandary, I guess. I just found out about Acrobat's "Run Form Field Recognition" function (I have always done forms manually) AND how to tweak a form in InDesign so that said Acrobat function will recognize fields as easily as possible.

I think this is useful information which should be disseminated, and if I were searching on Google, I'd want to find that answer on a Stack Exchange site.

But I already know the answer to the question (How do I tweak an InDesign form so that Acrobat recognizes the fields easily?), and I even know where to look (InDesigner podcast).

I don't want to post my question and then post my own answer; that seems onanistically silly (even if there is a badge for it). But if I know the answer, is it bad form to ask the question?

Comment: Totally acceptable. Later I'll dig out Jeff's post where he supports this.

Comment: @Farray [Here it is](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). It's also linked to in the [FAQ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: @Yannis thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly ask questions which you already know the answer. A few guidelines:

1. Give other people a chance to answer the question before you post your answer. You don't have to in general answer, but at least wait a day or two before you post your own answer.
2. Make sure it is an interesting question, more so than most questions.

Comment: 1) Do I in fact have to post an answer? 2) Given my sketch in the question above, would you consider that to be an interesting question?

Comment: No, you sure don't. I'm not the best judge as to what's an interesting question either, so...

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to post my question and then post my own answer; that seems onanistically silly

On the contrary, it's good to share knowledge.

> Give other people a chance to answer the question before you post your answer. You don't have to in general answer, but at least wait a day or two before you post your own answer.

Disagreed, post asap, no need to have others search for an answer if you know it already.